# Dynamics AX 2012 Programmatically Create Data Definition Group

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

Has anyone every tried to programmatically create Data Definition Groups?

Basically, create the group, then add the tables to it.

Tried doing this just by exploring the tables behind the AX form and it didn't seem to want to play nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a data definition group programmatically isn't terribly difficult, but when you say that, it makes me think that you want to do this to systematically do "something" with tables.

If that's the case, then you shouldn't worry about the definition groups, because that's more of a user-interface that uses the `SysDataImport` and `SysDataExport` classes, which you should just use directly through code.

Here is an example I blogged about not too long ago that shows how to import/export your MorphX settings.  You can see where I add the Import/Export tables and do the work.

http://alexondax.blogspot.com/2015/06/how-to-exportimport-your-morphx-vcs.html

Comment: We have an isv solution with a lot of setup tables.  Our customers often want to export their settings and move them to other servers.  Every time they work with a new server, they have to create a definition group first.  Thought I'd save them some time by giving them a job that creates the definition group for them.

Comment: Well then my post seems to be exactly what you need. In some Dev environments, we use MorphX for a version control system.  When we need to restore a database copy to it, we want to preserve our MorphX settings.  The job exports the 5 needed tables with prompt, then when we want to bring in the other settings, the job lets us import the file previously exported to populate those tables. I think you could literally just change the tables in the job to your tables, and it would probably run and do exactly what you want. You would obviously put the code in a class and give it a menu item, etc.